# I'm not able to center an element in a Chrome extension that I'm forking

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I need help with a Chrome extension that I am forking,

It's an extension that help to manage tabs and I want the graphically representation of the tabs to be centered in the browser window.

I've tried numerous CSS property but nothing change and I don't understand why ?

Things like  this usually work but in this nothing change.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

Here's a screenshot to have a better understanding: 
[image]

Here's the link  to the extension as it is right now if it can help you to help me: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ok7zj2fwqp9bdgu/TabsPaneMikhoulFork.7z

Regards !

Comment: Ensure the parent div isn't floated

Comment: @MPaul Sadly the div isn't floated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you've forced the `tabsPane` element to be `width:100% !important` whereas the original extension set a width in pixel which is automatically recalculated on resize.

What you can do instead is set the following properties for `tabsPane`:

```
// The 100px will automatically be divided as the left and right margins.
width:-webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
width:calc(100% - 100px);
```

`calc` is a property that's been [supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) in Chrome since *Chrome 19* so there should be no issues there. If you were to replicate this plugin's design to another legacy browser and `calc` isn't supported, there are numerous ways to center a div with an unknown width.

CSS-Tricks has an excellent article on this: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#center-horizontally

Comment: thanks for your help, I've tried but it's the same results sadly, as soon I resize the browser windows the "tiles" don't want to center.  Here's a screencast to show you exactly what happen when I resize the browser window: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cFj6Dzqjuk

Comment: I noticed your `calc` is at 109% ratehr than 100%, but I don't think this would be the underlying issue. Can you ensure that the parent element `appleOddRow` has a width of 100%

Comment: You're right @mPaul it's because I was playing with the mouse scroll wheel to change the value and see what happen.